# How to send Email's through godaddy with PHPMailer?

Tags: php

I'm trying for several day send e-mails from my website through godaddy account.
I don't know if there's any special configuration at server side(godaddy)
I don't know if I did any mistake with my php code too.
I really need figure out how can I send email's.
Thanks, Ricardo.

```
enter code here
    try {

        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->isSMTP();
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
        $mail->DKIM_domain = '**********';

        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        $mail->Host        = "a2plcpnl0321.prod.iad2.secureserver.net";

        $mail->Port        = 465;

        $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
        //Username to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username    = "***************.com";
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password    = "**99KKll";
        $mail->SMTPSecure  = 'ssl';
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom('****************.com', '*******');
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        //$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress('**************.com', '*****');

        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
        $mail->Body = "<i>This is the Link to change your password:</i>";
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';


        //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
        } 
        print_r($mail);
```

Comment: So....`$mail->ErrorInfo` produces nothing? Please share your secrets

Comment: Most of the hosting providers have the ports closed. I would suggest to try contacting GoDaddy support and tell them to open the port.

Answer (score 0):

are you catching the errors?

```
try {
    // your mail code
    // $mail->send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: Yes, and even say's that the e'mail was send with success, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-a2plcpnl0321.prod.iad2.secureserver.net ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2 Fri, 26 Feb 2016 16:15:57 -0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO warneracademy.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-a2plcpnl0321.prod.iad2.secureserver.net Hello a2plcpnl0321.prod.iad2.secureserver.net [*************]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: cmVxdWVzdEB3YXJuZXJhY2FkZW15LmNvbQ==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: Kio5OUtLbGw=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<**************>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<*************>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 23:15:52 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Ricardo Scarpim <**************>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: WarnerAcademy <**************>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: PHPMailer SMTP test
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <5fa4a06963e0e5c2e64a8e88e553bc10@warneracademy.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.13 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_5fa4a06963e0e5c2e64a8e88e553bc10"
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_5fa4a06963e0e5c2e64a8e88e553bc10
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a plain-text message body
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_5fa4a06963e0e5c2e64a8e88e553bc10
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <i>This is the Link to change your password:</i>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_5fa4a06963e0e5c2e64a8e88e553bc10--
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1aZRc5-001CJG-Tk
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 a2plcpnl0321.prod.iad2.secureserver.net closing connection
Message sent!
```

Comment: That is the message from console, I can't understand that, it is wrong or what ??

Answer (score 0):

after many attemps.. this works for me in Godaddy[20/12/2017]

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//$mail->isSMTP();                                      
//isSMTP seems to be the problem..  because it sends locally
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 0;
//$mail->DKIM_domain = '127.0.0.1';
$mail->Host       = "localhost";
$mail->Port       = "25";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->Username   = "";
$mail->Password   = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the solution the original post was looking for, but for anyone who is dealing with the limitations of sending emails through GoDaddy or any other hosting service, this could be a useful workaround. This solution will allow you to send emails via Gmail from any other account you have login credentials for.

Requirements:
Gmail account, XAMPP or similar local web server, PHPMailer library
(tutorials on how to use XAMPP and PHPMailer are abundantly available online)

Instructions:
 1. Go to "Settings" in your Gmail account. Under "Accounts and Import," add "youraccount@domainyouown.com" in the "Send Mail As" section.
 2. In your PHP script (using the PHPMailer library), replace the credentials in the following lines of code with your Gmail credentials and the account you'd like to send from:

```
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'yourpassword';
$mail->setFrom('youraccount@domainyouown.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addReplyTo('youraccount@domainyouown.com', 'Your Name');
```

Added benefits of this method:

1. Emails are **authenticated**. I spent quite a while trying to achieve this via GoDaddy, to no avail. This removes the "possible spam" notification that is sometimes present with emails sent through hosting server relays...
2. Emails are sent **faster**. For whatever reason, the emails I sent via GoDaddy using PHP's mail() function took a few minutes to go through. Gmail takes seconds.
3. Copies of the emails you send actually show up in your Gmail "Sent" folder. This was also something that I could not achieve via GoDaddy, and I was told by customer support that this is a limitation of the service.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on any of this or suggest a better method. It's just the most elegant solution I've found so far!